# ROOT constant in php and html

Tags: php, html

I have the following php file where 'ROOT' was used. What is this ROOT thing? and how come is it not recognised?

```
<?php

...
        if($result == "")
        {
            header("Location: " . ROOT . "profile");
            die;
        }else
        {
...
?>
```

Also in html file, something like `<a href="<?=ROOT?>messages">` ... was used. What is this ROOT thing in this context?

Comment: A constant, defined by for example [define](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). If it is not recognized it most likely is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define("ROOT", "http://example.com");
```

`define` — Defines a named constant

If that constant could not be found in this php file, may be it is defined in another php file, which be `require` or `include` in this php file.